# Upload multiple files with associated names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which has a upload button. I have another button which adds another file upload field. What I want to do is let the user choose the file he wants to upload and also let him associate the file with a name. For example, I have a model which looks like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLink { get; set; }
}
```

When a user uploads a file, it gets sent to a folder on my machine and then the associated filename will be put into the FileLink field. My problem is associated the file upload with a filename field and allowing the user to add multiple upload forms to the form where they can also associate those forms with fields. Currently If I do something like IEnumerable, it will get all the uploaded files but without the associated names. What should I do? Is there a good plugin for stuff like this?

Comment: You could replace `FileName` with `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` and `FileLink` with `List<FileLink>`

Comment: @PKKG So that means there's not really a clear distinction but I'll have to loop through each list and the 0th of each list is the first item and the 1st is the second? Others no way to bind a name to a httppostedfilebase?

Comment: No need to worry about model binding as IEnumerable will take care of it

Comment: Maybe I was not bring clear. On my main page, when a user chooses and IMG from his HDD, he has the option to add a title to it with the text box right next to it. I was wondering how to bind the specific file he uploaded with the text box right next to it. Since List<HttpPosted> will just be all the files posted on the page.